# Barcode Encryption of Personal Identifiers (or alternatives suggested by you)

Tags: barcode

I am trying to create a health application of a rather sensitive nature which will require some form of cryptography/obfuscation. There is a health study in which once a year, known individuals with permanent and recognisable identifier numbers (eg KIG0005001 as an individuals identifier) walk into the clinic, are identified, have their blood tested as part of a study. Next year, the same happens again, as this is a longitudinal study. Now the results of the blood test should NOT be able to be traceable to an actual individual (HIV status, etc are highly sensitive bits of information that should not be linkable with actual individuals due to their right to privacy), but it is IMPERATIVE that we can identify year on year which blood samples belong to one unique individual (without knowing WHO the individual actually is, the emphasis is on the blood samples being traceable to one individual, not the individual).

My idea (and here is where am asking for your expertise in cryptography and obfuscation) is that when the individual visits the clinic they come with an identifying card with their regular id number KIG0005001 . This number is entered into a system where via an algorithm/encryption it spits out a barcode (based on the original id KIG0005001 , therefore any future visits should produce the SAME barcode for a particular individual) which can be printed out as stickers. These barcode stickers are the ones to be used to identify the samples (stick em on the samples). The stickers should have the following information in them: unique identifier (via barcode?), the round number that the sample was taken (samples will be taken once a year, so year 1= round 1) and date sample taken.

Is this possible? What are the alternatives? How/What should I do in terms of transforming KIG0005001 into an encrypted barcode which is repeatable year on year (so blood sample can always be traced back to the same source). Am programming in Java.

Thanks in advance,
Tumaini

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, I don't think it needs to be in the barcode section.
First of all, there is no way to keep everything 100% secure... but you can make it more complicated to be understood by a human.

It's the same thing as the passport controversy... A biometric passport must be secure: it's not possible to read the information without knowing the "private key". But let's say you read and record everybody's passport that enters your store and save it to a database. You will be able to trace who is coming back and even what they previously bought since you have their passport's ID...

To make the life harder for your employees, you need to generate an ID that will match the real person's ID. So if the employee is testing the blood of KIG0005001, they will receive a different unique ID for that day; the computer will know how to link them up. So that your employee has no idea who is this number at that moment...

Cryptography is probably useless here since you work with IDs. Even a gibberish data repeated multiple time is still an ID.